# Can't access to field inside Field

Tags: c#

Need to access m_fullDescriptor to get value in it however I can't access the field that inside another field like below image.

Using below code to get field which successfully i got but when i search m_pm or m_fullDescriptor in pmCS can't find them.

How can i access it?

```
var specFields = con.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "pmCS");
```

Then i try to access 'm_pm' like below;

```
var specFields = con.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "pmCS").GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "m_pm");
```

It throws an error;

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching
>   element'

[image]

Comment: So where is the code that tried to do that? You'll have to get the type and value of the `pmCS` field to be able to access it's own fields.

Comment: i debugged and watch fromvisual studio and there was not.

Comment: How do you mean "there was not"? Either `pmCS`, `m_pm` and `m_fullDescriptor` are public fields and you can just access them or you'll have to use reflection to get access to the non-publoc values. Where I warn you to be carefull, there is normally a reason fields are non-public and the one maintaining that part of the code usually doesn't expect other accessing those fields meaning one library upgrade can suddenly produce run time exceptions due to the private field not existing anymore

Comment: i know the cons but i need to access the value. edited the question. i try to get it but no luck.

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a [mcve], ideally formatted so we didn't have to scroll a lot in order to see all the code at once.

Comment: But fundamentally, I *believe* you're calling `GetType().GetFields()` on a `FieldInfo`, so that's giving you the fields of the `FieldInfo` type, *not* on the type that the field represents. With a complete example, we could easily correct that and verify that it works...

Comment: well, i am using odp.net and trying to connect to databases in this example. So i'm afraid  reproduciable example can't be shared. Basically i just want to access value on field inside the field.

Answer (score 0):

GetFields() returns FieldInfo[]. FiledInfo is of type RtFieldInfo. What you need is the field's actual Type, and thus you should make use of the FieldType property of the FieldInfo class like this:

---

```
var specFields = con.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "pmCS").FieldType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "m_pm");
```

> *Notice the use of the* **FieldType** *property*.

Comment: thanks i think i got that. but now how can i get the value of the field? When i use getValue(object obj), it needs objects. however all i want is just returning string to assign.

Comment: @S.Doe Use it like this - "specFields.GetValue(con.pmCS);". And don't forget to like the answer if it was helpful.